# VSCode StatusBar button creation in extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

How do I add a button in my VSCode extension which you can click like this:
[image]

What I've tried is:

```js
const pres = vscode.window.createStatusBarItem(vscode.StatusBarAlignment.Left)
pres.text = 'Click to Connect to Discord Presence'
pres.command = 'test-extension.presence'
pres.show()
```

but that doesn't seem to work, It does show when I run the command in `CTRL + SHIFT + P`/`Command Pallete`, but how do I make the button show without needing to run the command first?

Comment: Thank you, that worked and maybe you should just answer it not comment so that I could accept your answer and at the same time you'll get a rep points since you've been helping me since yesterday

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the activation of the extension to `"*"` in `package.json` and create the status bar button in the `activate()` function